# Multiple Connections in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I've been using node.js for a while and just playing around with the modules. I have a question, Is it possible to connect multiple node.js servers and have a communication link between them?

what I mean to say is, I have 3 node.js severs each handling different operations and different clients. I want to create link between these servers such that each servers can communicate.

server1 ==> [database]

server2 ==> room1[client1,client2,client3]

server3 ==> room2[client4,client5,client6]

I can create a connection between 2 servers using 'net', but how to do with multiple servers?

Comment: Just a guess. You can start nodejs 3 times on different processes, each time listening on a different port...?

Comment: socket.io makes it easy to pass events and data between systems.

Comment: I've used socket.io for commincation between server and client but I am not really sure whether it works for communication between servers as each server has different port.

Comment: Also can we connect the servers internally with using any ID or it has to be connected only using the port address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of options here:

- some kind of hub server (server 4). Servers 1-3 all symmetrical and are clients for server 4. Whenever message needs to be broadcasted, server 4 sends it to all clients. Possible solutions: dbus, 0mq/rabbitmq, [redis pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub), socket.io
- [udp broadcasts](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_setbroadcast_flag)
- configure each server to have list of all servers and manually broadcast all incoming packets by iterating connections to neighbours. Need to use some kind of TTL field to avoid loops

Comment: Is there any way we can connect to a node.js server without using the port address??

Comment: what do you mean by "connect" and "without using"? If its TCP or UDP then you need to know port number. If "without using" is "without configuring" then you can use some kind of discovery protocol like multicast DNS.

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. Yes, without configuring I would like to establish a communication link between multiple node.js servers, is that possible?

Comment: use pub/sub pattern with hub server. That way each server need to know only about hub and not about others